I'm curious on what the downsides of the public-key encryption method from my research project could be
As part of my final BS degree research project, I had to work with an encryption method based on research done in my university. What surprised me, is that while the method is very simple, I can't really imagine what its downsides from security standpoint could be. I'm looking both for feedback and perhaps some insight on how to cryptanalize this method. The method is not mine, it's simply part of my research project and I'm simply curious. I'd be very grateful if someone had the time to share some insight! In the bottom you can also find an implementation of the method in C++, but before that I'll give its general description.
Here's a description of the method. Let $n,m$ be natural numbers. We've a class of $n \times m$ tables consisting of permutations from $S_{n+m}$. Henceforth all the permutations will be from $S_{n+m}$. Let $T$ be one of these tables. We put into correspondence the vectors $(y_1,\dots,y_n) \in \{1,\dots,m\}^m$ and the product $T[1][y_1]\dots T[n][y_n]$. What unifies these tables into a single class are the following two properties

Let $T$ be an arbitrary table from that class. $\forall y', y'' \in \{1,\dots,m\}^m$ and $y' \neq y'', T[1][y'_1]\dots T[n][y'_n] \neq T[1][y''_1]\dots T[n][y''_n]$.
There exists an algorithm $\operatorname{cascade}(a)$ such that $\forall y \in \{1,\dots,m\}^m, \operatorname{cascade}(T[1][y_1]\dots T[n][y_n]) = (y_1,\dots,y_n)$.

Now pick $m = 2^k, k > 0$. Then $\mathbb{Z}\cap [0,m-1] \leftrightarrow \{0,1\}^k$, i.e. every integer from $[0,m-1]$ can be expressed using exactly $k$ bits and every $k$ bit word can be converted to an integer from $[0,m-1]$.
Suppose we have a message which we divide into equal blocks. Each block will be encrypted separately. Each block has the length $kn$. By reading k-bit words at a time, to each word corresponds a number from $[0,m-1]$ and by adding $1$ we get a number from $[1,m]$. Thus to each block corresponds a vector $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ and to each such vector corresponds a product $T[1][y_1]\dots T[n][y_n]$.
Now, let's modify $T$ in the following way. Pick arbitrarily $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n \in S_{n+m}$. For each row of $T$ up to the penultimate row, substitute each element $T[i][j]$ of the $i$-th row with $\beta_i T[i][j] \beta^{-1}_{i+1}$. Whereas for the last row, substitute each elemenet $T[n][j]$ with $\beta_n T[n][j] \beta_1$. It's easy to notice, that to the vectors $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ now will correspond the products $\beta_1 T[1][y_1]\dots T[n][y_n] \beta_1$. Denote this new table with $T'$. Basically, $T'$ is the obfuscated version of $T$ and $\forall y, \beta_1^{-1} T'[1][y_1]\dots T'[n][y_n] \beta^{-1}_1 = T[1][y_1]\dots T[n][y_n]$.
Now pick randomly one of these tables, obfuscate it with permutations $\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$, denote the obfuscated table with $T'$. $T'$ will be the public key whereas $\beta_1$ will be the private key. The result of the encryption of a block is a product $T'[1][y_1]\dots T'[n][y_n]$. The encryption is reversible if one has the private key.
It is shown, that unless the opponent were to successfully guess the table $T$ or the permutation $\beta_1$, in order to decrypt a block they'd need to solve an NP-complete problem with a worst case of $m^n$ operations. (I've found a way to crack the method if the opponent manages to guess the table $T$. Also if we pick $n=64, m=16$, $m^n$ will be equal to $2^{256}$). The class of such tables is big enough to be meaningless to try to bruteforce.  Thus the method is bruteforce proof. Whereas an algebraic attack would probably be impossible without having the table $T$ as there's simply not enough information without it.
$\operatorname{cascade}$ has a complexity of $O(n)$, thus encryption and decryption will be done very fast.
Here is the link of the implementation of the method in C++: https://github.com/H-a-y-k/PublicKeyEncryption. Note that here the method is implemented for a sample $T$. But in general $T$ will be unknown and almost impossible to guess. Nonetheless, the implementation does not depend on the contents of $T$, so this doesn't affect the analysis of the method.

At first glance, it sounds similar to the Knapsack public key cryptosystem proposed (and broken) decades ago.  Not sure if similar attacks would work against it, though...

@poncho I think you're on point. I didn't know such a system existed before. My prof indicated that the NP-complete problem is reducible to the knapsack problem.

Actually, all NP-complete problems are reducible to each other.  Now, with Knapsack, the 'easy-to-'solve' piece is to use 'superincreasing-bins' (so that bin i is more than the total of bits i+1...n.  I'm not sure what technique your cascade function is using to solve the easy case - depending on how different it is from the superincreasing bins, the knapsack attacks might or might not be adaptable.

@poncho there's a very short description of the $\operatorname{cascade}$ function here in pages 1-2: https://shorturl.at/CX3CT (sorry for shortened url, the original didn't work on stackexchange).  In my case the table $T$ is constructed in this way: we build a strong generating set of $S_{n+m}$ which can be written as a $n+m \times n+m$ table. $T$ will be the top $n$ rows and last $m$ columns. The $cascade$ function of the strong generting works for $T$ too.

Small correction (probably doesn't matter): the strong generating set can be written as a $n+m \times n+m$ table where the part that's below the diagonal is not used. (Basically an upper triangular table including the diagonal).
